# The need to use inherit in CSS

Tags: css

Been looking at a premium theme and see that for various text and elements on the page, when inspected - many have inherit and 0 for the values.

Why would these not be left blank if they are not required and automatically inherited from the parent? Does it perhaps save on load time?

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
```

Comment: I would imagine it makes the file size larger and this increases load time.

Comment: In that case it would make sense to leave them out. But they've been left in for some reason. These are top paid themes from Themeforest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done to override browser defaults.

Most browsers themselves apply their own style declarations to make basic HTML pages look prettier. Unfortunately these style declarations often clash with how a designer wants a web page to look. The way to overcome this is to *reset* the styles to what they should be by default.

#### Example

A good example of this is with heading and `p` tags. Take the following example:

```html
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>Woah, that's a big heading!</p>
```

Without any custom styling applied, these elements use styles provided by the browser. One of the styles used here is `margin`, and that's what's putting the large gaps between each element.

We can reset these ourselves by setting the `margin` to `0`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>Woah, that's a big heading!</p>
```

---

Because of the need to *reset* such styles public stylesheets like [Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) exist, whose intention is to do nothing more than reset (and normalize) all elements to look the same across different browsers.

Comment: Does this explain the use of `inherit` for some of the the CSS properties?

Comment: @hungerstar I guess my answer ignores that. However that's just the same as `margin: 0` here. `inherit` is used to let the element inherit the given style declaration from its parent. The same `h1` element used above has a browser-default style of `font-weight: bold`; we could use `inherit` here to allow the `h1` element to use the `font-weight` of its containing element instead.